# How to check programmatically if Zookeeper is running

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We are trying to check whether Zookeeper is started or not in our application.

How can we achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

From shell script you can also use `nc -z` command - very handy when startup script for your application checks it first, and your application doesn't care about checking ZK

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure Zookeeper is up and running is to connect to it.

If you are using Kafka, you can reuse the the Zookeeper library it comes with, `org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient`.

Just call:

```
ZkClient client = new ZkClient("localhost:2181", 5000);
```

The second argument is the connection timeout. In this case, it will try to connect for 5 seconds. If it's unable to connect it throws `ZkTimeoutException`.

Comment: after client exists (means you got a connection, with no exception) you should do a call to see ZK is able to respond, and then close the connection

    `client.numberOfListeners();
    client.close();`